# Find the radius of the sphere with respect to R and r

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

The figure above shows a straight cone of base radius $R$ in which a sphere is inscribed that intersects the side of the cone in a circle of radius $r$. Point $C$ is the center of the base of the cone and tangent to the sphere. Points $A$ and $B$ are located on the same generatrix of the cone, where $A$ belongs to the circle of radius $r$ and $B$ to the circle of radius $R$.

Based on this hypothetical situation, judge the following items.
The radius of the sphere is $\dfrac{R\sqrt r}{\sqrt{2R-r}}$

(S: True)

[image]

I try:

$CB = CA = R$

$\triangle VAO \sim \triangle VCB \sim \triangle VTA$

$\dfrac{VO+re}{VT}=\dfrac{r}{R}=\dfrac{VA}{VA+R}$

$\dfrac{VO}{VA+R}=\dfrac{re}{R}=\dfrac{VA}{VO+re}$

$\dfrac{r}{re}=\dfrac{VA}{VO}=\dfrac{VT}{VA}$

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made a great start. As shown in the diagram below, draw from $A$ to meet $CB$ perpendicularly at $D$, and let $\lvert AD\rvert = h$.

[image: Diagram of OP, with perpendicular line AD and line length h added]

Thus, $\lvert DB\rvert = R - r$. Using the Pythagorean theorem with $\triangle ADB$ gives that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
h^2 + (R - r)^2 & = R^2 \\
h^2 + R^2 - 2rR + r^2 & = R^2 \\
h^2 & = 2rR - r^2 \\
h & = \sqrt{r(2R - r)}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since $\triangle VTA \sim \triangle ADB$, then

$$\frac{\lvert VA\rvert}{\lvert VT\rvert} = \frac{R}{h} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Using the reciprocal of your final result, and \eqref{eq1A}, we get from \eqref{eq2A} that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{re}{r} & = \frac{R}{h} \\
re & = \frac{rR}{\sqrt{r(2R - r)}} \\
re & = \frac{R\sqrt{r}}{\sqrt{2R - r}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Comment: HI, do you have any ideas for this problem?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708162/find-angle-x-in-the-circle-below

Comment: @petaarantes I spent some time shortly after you originally posted your question, and have done so again now, checking on it. However, all I got was that $\theta = \beta$ plus, doing angle-chasing in various ways, that $90^{\circ} = 4\theta + \frac{x}{2}$. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find another equation involving $\theta$ and $x$ to then determine what $x$, and $\theta$, were specifically. Good luck in determining how to solve it yourself, or in getting an answer that makes it clear to you how to determine the value.

Answer (score 1):

From $\triangle VTA \sim \triangle VCB$,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{VA}{VA+R} &= \frac{r}{R}\\
VA\cdot R &= r(VA+R)\\
VA(R-r) &= rR\\
VA &= \frac{rR}{R-r}
\end{align*}$$

From $\triangle VAO \sim \triangle VCB$,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{VO+re}{VA} &= \frac{R}{re}\\
\frac{VO}{VA} &= \frac{R}{re} - \frac{re}{VA}\\
&= \frac{R}{re} - \frac{re(R-r)}{rR}\\
\end{align*}$$

From $\triangle ATO \sim \triangle VAO$,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{re}{VO} &= \frac{r}{VA}\\
re &= r \frac{VO}{VA}\\
&= \frac{rR}{re} - \frac{re(R-r)}{R}\\
re\left(1+\frac{R-r}{R}\right) &= \frac{rR}{re}\\
(re)^2 &= \frac{rR^2}{2R-r}\\
re &= \frac{R\sqrt r}{\sqrt{2R-r}}
\end{align*}$$